# How to `==` to a newline character in vim

Tags: vim

I want to match newline character in test case of an if statement in vim script.

How do I match to a newline character ?
The reason for this is, when I want to get the output of a system command and check if it matches something, and then execute a command, the `system()` command in vim can do the work, but it returns with a newline at the end. So I am not able to match properly.

For example, I hope you know about `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree`, it prints `true` with a newline at the end if we are inside a git repository, and `false` with a newline at the end if we are not inside a git repository.

I want to use this command inside vim script and run a command only if I am inside a git repository.
But since this command returns `true` or `false` with a newline at the end, I am unable to use the following snippet of code to do this. Because `system("git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree")` returns `true` or `false` with a newline at the end.

```
if system("git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree") == 'true'
  echo "Inside a git repository"
else 
  echo "Not inside a git repository"
endif
```

What can I use instead of `if system("git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree") == 'true'` to match newline at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"true\n"` to check the newline. Note that double quotes are used for special characters. See `:h string`

```
echo system('git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree') == "true\n"
" 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the newline with a substitution:

```
system("git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree")->substitute('\n','','') == 'true'
```

or compare against a regular expression:

```
system("git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree") =~ 'true'
```

or get a list from the external command, with a single item because there is only one actual line in the output:

```
systemlist("git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree")[0] == 'true'
```

See `:help substitute()`, `help expr-=~`, and `:help systemlist()`.